# Matching single word in colum with multi word string

Tags: php, mysql

We are validating bank names against account numbers.

A third party API returns the name of the bank when supplied with an account number. This is a multi word string and there is no fixed list of values it can return.

We need to check the bank returned by the API against a list of bank names within a table in our database. To do this we have a table with synonyms for bank names which we wish to use for matching. Please see the SQL below.

To do this, we would hope to find a match of 'kong', 'hong' or 'shanghai' in our table if the API returned 'Hong Kong and Shanghai Banking Corporation' or 'Hong Kong & Shanghai Banking Corp' etc.

Seeing we wish to match a single word in our table, against a multi word string, I am at a loss as to how to do this in MySQL.

SQL for the bank names table in our database....

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bank_names` (
  `bank_name_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bank` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bank_name_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bank` (`bank`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `bank_names` (`bank`) VALUES
('kong'),
('hong'),
('shanghai'),
('westminster'),
('citi'),
('citibank');
```

I have tried...

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bank_names` 
WHERE bank LIKE '%Hong Kong and Shanghai Banking Corporation%';
```

This obviously does not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use `FIND_IN_SET` or `IN`..., Just convert your string to array and use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN()` statement not `LIKE` :

```
SELECT * FROM `bank_names`
WHERE `bank` in('Hong','Kong','and','Shanghai'...)
```

Or with `LIKE` :

```
SELECT * FROM `bank_names` t
WHERE '%Hong Kong and Shanghai Banking Corporation' like concat('%',t.bank,'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bank_names` 
WHERE  'Hong Kong and Shanghai Banking Corporation' LIKE CONCAT('%', bank, '%') ;
```

This should return the first three sample records as listed in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` or `FIND_IN_SET`..

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bank_names` 
WHERE bank IN ('Hong', 'Kong', 'and', 'Shanghai', 'Banking', 'Corporation');
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bank_names` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(bank, 'Hong', 'Kong', 'and', 'Shanghai', 'Banking', 'Corporation');
```